# Package does not have nearby devices permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm writing an Android app that calls `WifiManager#startLocalOnlyHotspot`.  However, it crashes with

```
java.lang.SecurityException: package=com.example.localserver UID=10162 does not have nearby devices permission.
```

However, I've got

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NEARBY_WIFI_DEVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
...
```

in my AndroidManifest.xml file.

This is being run on an emulated Android 13.

Comment: Some of your permissions (e.g. the NEARBY_WIFI_DEVICES) are runtime permissions, which means declaring them in AndroidManifest is not enough. If all permissions are granted and the issue still persists, you can try removing temporarily the location related permissions and setting "neverForLocation" for the nearby permission.

Comment: My phone never prompted me for the permission.  Is there somewhere I can grant it manually?

Comment: For test purposes you can grant all permissions in app settings

Comment: Want to post that as the answer?